# A special type of ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

I am looking for some references that contained a study of ideals with the following *-property:

Let $I $ be an ideal of a commutative ring with ideantity. The ideal $I $ has the *-property if $I\subseteq \sum_{ i\in A  }I_i $, where $\{   I_i  \}_{ i\in A  } $ is a family of ideals of $R $,  then there exists $j\in  A $ such that $I\subseteq I_j $.

Comment: Can you give an example other than the zero ideal?

Comment: In a local ring if the maximal ideal is pricipal it has the *- property.

Comment: @Corbennick Well, one obvious example would be to take an Artinian ring whose ideals are linearly ordered. The unique minimal ideal $I$ would satisfy this condition.

Comment: I think I recall considering the "finite" version of this question before ($|A|$ being finite) in dual rings.  I think i was looking for ways to dualize the definition of "prime ideal," and the annihilator map was the candidate. I don't recall finding special names for it.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Clearly for Noetherian uniserial rings, sure. I don't think your claim is true though in non-Noetherian ones, though. It seems like if you take an infinite strictly ascending chain, and the union $I$ would be contained in the sum (=union) of the chain, and yet it wouldn't be contained in any of the elements of the chain.

Comment: If $I$ has two distinct maximal proper subideals $J,K$, then $J+K=I$ but $I \not\subseteq J,K$, so $I$ does not have the $*$-property. If $I$ has proper subideals but does not have any maximal proper subideals, then (I think?) $I$ must be the union of a maximal chain of subideals, so $I$ does not have the $*$-property. If that's right (?) then for $I$ to have the $*$-property it's necessary for $I$ to either have no proper subideals, $I=(0)$, or $I$ has a unique maximal proper subideal. I don't know if that's sufficient though.

Comment: Trivia: (1) Every $*$-ideal is principal. (2) If a domain $R$ contains a non-zero $*$-ideal, then $R$ is local. In particular, a domain whose ideals are $*$-ideals is a discrete valuation ring.

Comment: Dear Luc Guyot, can you give a proof for the came 2 of your comment?

Comment: @user119996 Let $Ra$ be a non-zero principal $*$-ideal of a domain $R$. Write $1 = x + y$ for $x, y \in R$. We are done if we prove that $x$ or $y$ is a unit. As $Ra = Rax + Ray$, we deduce that $Ra = Rax$ or $Ra = Ray$. The result follows.