# Maximal subideal of an ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, ideals

For a commutative ring $R$ with unity, I am looking for an equivalent condition for an ideal $T$ to have the property that $T$ contains a unique maximal proper subideal, equivalently, the sum of proper subideals of $T$ is not equal to $T$.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291748/a-special-type-of-ideals

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644665/which-modules-have-exactly-one-maximal-submodule . In particular, this answer implies that if R is a Noetherian local ring, an ideal has precisely one maximal subideal *if and only if* it is a nonzero principal ideal.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful to you but a module for which "the sum of two proper submodules is not equal to the whole module" is called a [hollow module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_module), which is basically the dual notion to a uniform module. So you might be talking about a hollow ideals.

Answer (score 9):

**Claim:** 
Let $T$ be an ideal in a commutative ring. If $T$ contains
a unique maximal proper subideal, then $T$ is principal.

*Proof*: Indeed take any element outside the unique maximal proper subideal. The ideal generated by that cannot be a proper subideal and hence has to be $T$.

So, this suggests that this is a very special property. For instance, that maximal subideal would have to contain the square of any generator of $T$ and if those generators are not zero-divisors, then they are associate (i.e. they can only differ by a unit multiple). If any generator is a zero-divisor then every element in $T$ is a zero-divisor. I think you can continue this line of thought to derive more special properties when this holds.

There is also a partial converse:

**Claim:**
Let $T$ be a non-zero principal ideal in a commutative ring. Then every proper subideal of $T$ is contained in an ideal that is maximal among proper subideals in $T$.

(By the usual proof of existence of maximal ideals)

*Proof*: Let $T\subseteq R$ be a principal ideal generated by $t\in T$, $T'\subsetneq T$  a proper subideal, and consider the set of ideals $I\subseteq T$ such that $T'\subseteq I$, $t\not\in I$ which is the same as the set of proper subideals of $T$ containing $T'$. If there is a chain of such ideals $\ldots\subseteq I_\lambda\subseteq \dots$ with $\lambda\in \Lambda$, then $t\not\in J:=\cup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}I_\lambda$ is an upper bound of the chain and hence the statement follows by Zorn's lemma.

However, of course, this does not mean that there is a unique one...

On the positive side, here is a situation where what you are hoping for holds:

**Claim:** If $R$ is a DVR, then the ideals in $R$ form a totally ordered set.

*Proof*: This follows essentially from the definition of a DVR.

So, I suppose one can conclude that this holds sometime, but for most ideals in most rings it does not.

Comment: Well to be entirely accurate one has to exclude the zero ideal from this...

Comment: @PeterHeinig the second statement "Claim" of the OP "Let $T$ be a principal ideal... then $T$ contains [...] proper subideals" is false for $T=0$. To say that $\{0\}$ is maximal among proper subideals of $\{0\}$ is not vacuously true, it is false, because it says in particular that $\{0\}$ is a proper subset of $\{0\}$, which means the existence of an element in the empty set.

Comment: Actually the standard conclusion of Zorn's lemma gives a correct statement without excluding anything: any proper subideal (of a principal ideal) is contained in a maximal proper subideal

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: How do you get the upper-bound without the exclusion?

Comment: Well I admit it is sort of cheating but in fact it is not :D If you can give me a proper subideal of a principal ideal to try me, then this proper subideal can be generated by a nonzero $t$ and then I will argue as you did

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I don't understand your argument. Are you saying that any subideal of a principal ideal is also principal? How about $R=k[x,y,z]$ and $(xy,xz)\subseteq (x)$?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Given a proper subideal in a principal ideal $P$ I have to find a maximal proper subideal containing it. If there is a proper subideal in $P$ then $P=(t)$ for some nonzero $t$. Then the argument in your second claim shows that chains of proper subideals have upper bounds. Zorn's lemma then gives that every proper subideal is contained in a maximal proper subideal.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: OK, I finally understood your point and updated the claim. Just for the record, your first comment is talking about "excluding" which seems totally irrelevant (at the end you need to exclude the generator to get the upper bound).

Comment: Well in the first comment I also was not precise enough - I wanted to say there that in your second claim one should restrict to nonzero principal ideals. After that comment, I realized that one could do better by changing from "there are maximal proper subideals" to "every proper subideal is contained in a maximal one" (instead of restricting to nonzero principal ideals only).

Comment: Maybe it's worth pointing out that there is a popular class of rings with the above property for all (nonzero) iprincipal deals: Namely, local rings.