# A relation among the elements of a commutative ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R $ be a commutative ring with 1 and $0\not=a\in R $, I am looking for a condition on $a$ and on $R$ such that for every $b, c\in R$ such that $a=b+c$, there exists $r\in R$  such that $a=rb$ or $a=rc$? 
 (For example in **local** rings every **unit** element has this property)

Is there any geometric interpretation for such a property of special rings and their special elements?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Equivalently, for every $b \in R$, either $(a,b) = (b)$ or $(a,b) = (a-b)$. In particular, the ideal $(a,b)$ is always principal (but this statement is much weaker). This already puts severe restrictions on $a$.

Comment: If $a$ satisfies this in a domain and is not invertible, then, since $a=(a+ba^2)+(-ba^2)$ and $a\notin -ba^2A$ (unless $a=0$), we have $a\in a(1+ba)A$. Then $1+ba$ is invertible. Since this holds for all $b$, we deduce that $a$ belongs to the Jacobson radical of $A$.

Comment: If $R$ is a domain and $a \in R \setminus \{0\}$ has the desired property, then $R$ is local. To see this, write $1 = x + y$ with $x, y \in R$. We are done if $x$ or $y$ is a unit, but this follows from $a = ax + ay$.

Comment: The question is reminiscent of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291748/a-special-type-of-ideals#comment724398_291748.